# MySQL JSON to GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, json, group-concat, mysql-json

I have a JSON data in MySQL like this

```
[["D01","DATA 1"],["D02","DATA 2"],["D03","DATA 3"],["D04","DATA 4"],["D05","DATA 5"],["D06","DATA 6"]]
```

and I need it to format like this using GROUP_CONCAT

```
D01~D01~D03~D04~D05~D06
```

So far I have query like this...

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_EXTRACT(`data_field`, '$[*][0]') SEPARATOR '~') FROM `data_table`
```

...but it gives me this result

```
["D01", "D02", "D03", "D04", "D05", "D06"]
```

I don't know if this may be simple to you.  Thank you in advance.